# php date and daylight savings time confusion

Tags: php

I've got a problem and I'm 99% convinced its related to Daylight Savings Time starting yesterday.

The following script:

```
<?php
 $i=1383451200;
 echo $i, " ", date('Y-m-d I', @$i);
 echo "\n";
 $i = $i + 86400;
 echo $i, " ", date('Y-m-d I', @$i);
 echo "\n";
?>
```

(where 86400 is the number of seconds in a day)

gives the following output

1383451200 2013-11-03 1
1383537600 2013-11-03 0

2 timestamps, separated by the number of seconds in a day, fed into date(), giving the SAME date of 2013-11-03

Since it IS 11/3/2013 AND I KNOW we switched to Daylight Savings Time AND the I format specifier indicates one timestamp is in DST and one is not I think its safe to say I've got something misconfigured on my system.

The question is, how to fix it?  I have already done:

pecl install timezonedb

and added the following to php.ini

extension=/usr/lib/php5/20100525/timezonedb.so

on my system.

My system is Ubuntu 12.10 on a Macbook Pro and I'm using php 5

Any suggestions how to fix this?

Here's what I'm trying to do.  I want to print out date for every day in a month.

```
$startTime = strtotime($start);
$endTime = strtotime($end);
```

where $start and $end are strings of the form YYYY-MM-DD (and the user can specify them)

The individual days of the month are calculated as:

```
for ($i = $startTime; $i <= $endTime; $i = $i + 86400) {
     $thisDate = date('Y-m-d', $i); 
}
```

I want this to print out the date of every day in the month from the start to the end of the of the possibly user specified range.

Mark

Comment: Out of curiosity, what's the `@` in `@$i` there for? What warning could that possibly suppress?

Comment: @IMSoP $i is a number, but should be a string

Comment: @Kevin The second argument to [the `date()` function](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php) is `int $timestamp`.

Comment: Well yes, a day is never guaranteed to be 86400 seconds long. That's why you don't do time calculation like this.

Comment: @IMSoP I thought the @ had something to do with DST.  I was mistaken though because removing it from my test program had no effect.  I still get the same (bad) results.

Comment: @user1126515 `@` is the ["error suppression operator"](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.errorcontrol.php). `$i` in this case is just an integer being passed to a function, no extra syntax can affect how the function interprets that integer.

Comment: @deceze - yes, i know.  this is code i've inherited.  it was working well enough until now so i never fiddled with this bit.

the question is how do i correct the configuration?  i'm pretty sure its configuration based because this only happens on my test system.  the problem does not occur on the production system.

Comment: What you really need to fix is the *code*, not really the configuration. You simply do not work with times likes this, period. To give you concrete information on what exactly you *should* do, we'd need to know what exactly it is you are trying to do here. What timezones do you want to work in, what exactly do you want to do?

Comment: @deceze - i have edited the original question to explain what the code is trying to do.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You don't need to install any additional extensions to manipulate timezones, but you do need to read up on how PHP determines the default timezone for functions like `date()`, which is summarised on [the manual page for the `date_default_timezone_get()` function](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date-default-timezone-get.php).

Most likely your system's `php.ini` sets the `date.timezone` option to one of the geographical timezones [listed here](http://php.net/manual/en/timezones.php), which will take into account local Daylight Savings Times rules at that location.

If you run `date_default_timezone_set('UTC');` you should see your code outputting different dates as expected, as can be seen [in this live example](http://codepad.viper-7.com/fSMyyW). If you treat all your timestamps as though they were UTC, you can actually sidestep the issue of timezones and Daylight Savings Time completely, which may be appropriate if you don't actually know the timezone that the data you're working with should be interpreted as (e.g. if it comes from a remote source which doesn't specify that information).

However, as of PHP 5.2, there is a powerful [DateTime class](http://php.net/manual/en/class.datetime.php) which can encapsulate timezone information in the object, and includes methods for things like [adding an interval of time to a date](http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.add.php).

Note that the methods on DateTime alter the object, rather than returning a new object; as of PHP 5.5, there's also [DateTimeImmutable](http://php.net/manual/en/class.datetimeimmutable.php) to work the other way around.

Comment: Unfortunately your `in this live example` link has gone the way of most offsite links

Comment: @RiggsFolly Oops :( *Slaps self on wrist for not pasting the sample code back to the question*. I can't actually remember what was in it, but it doesn't look like it was the most interesting demo.

Comment: :) never mind answer helped to solve another OP's issue anyway. The demo was not really necesary. I not they did not UV so I will instead.