# Difference between two dates in months in php

Tags: php, date, timezone, date-difference

I am trying to get the difference between two months. For instance for below, I would want 2 months.

```
$datetime1 = date_create('2017-03-01');
$datetime2 = date_create('2017-04-30');
$interval = date_diff($datetime1, $datetime2);
echo $interval->format('%m months');
echo $interval->format('%d days');
```

This gives me 2 months and 1 day.

Comment: Funny, it gives me `1 months 29 days` which is what I would expect

Comment: Why would you want a result of `2 months` when there are not 2 months between those dates??

Comment: @RiggsFolly strangely enough; I too am getting `2 months1 days` on 5.6.24 if a default timezone isn't used. When using `date_default_timezone_set('America/New_York');` I get back `1 months29 days` - so this is the probable answer to this question.

Comment: @Fred-ii- :) I was just gona play with timezones as I just noticed the dates were at a time when clocks gets changed

Comment: if I use date_default_timezone_set('America/New_York'); then it shows 2
but with my actual time zone of   date_default_timezone_set('Africa/Nairobi'); it still shows 3

Comment: @user5349142 that may depend as to where your server is located and if it's hosted.

Comment: I am working via xampp on a local server.

Comment: @user5349142 or, if you made any changes to your system files and is on your own PC, make sure you did restart all services. Those changes will not take effect until you did.

Comment: @user5349142 Riggs made a good point in his comment under my answer about daylight savings - here is the link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19755820/php-date-and-daylight-savings-time-confusion

Comment: Do you get the correct answer if you use `date_default_timezone_set('UTC');`

Comment: @RiggsFolly that looks promising ^ yet the OP's not responding to a few comments I left.

Comment: with date_default_timezone_set('UTC'); I get the correct answer, but wont this affect the timezone over the entire project?

Comment: Not if you set it to `UTC` before running this code and then set it back to your timezone after this code is completed

Comment: ok will do that. Still not sure why this happens as I dont have daylight savings applicable in my location

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason why you're getting an incorrect result is most likely because you haven't set a default timezone, one for "your" timezone.

- http://php.net/manual/en/function.date-default-timezone-set.php

In adding and for example:

```
date_default_timezone_set('America/New_York');
```

returned the correct time difference, while not using it returned what you are presently getting.

Use the one for your own timezone, or set it in your system file(s).

From the manual http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.diff.php under "User Contributed Notes":

> *"When using datediff make sure your time zone is correct, for me on Windows 7 64 bit it behaved very strange when timezone was wrong (I was comparing now against time in database and exif metadata in photos). For example: date_default_timezone_set('Europe/Oslo');"*

and go through the rest of "User Contributed Notes".

- Another possible reason would be the server's location which is different from "your" position on "earth".

Relevant link from comments given by RiggsFolly:

- [php date and daylight savings time confusion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19755820/php-date-and-daylight-savings-time-confusion)

which could be at play here.

---

**Edit:**

After noticing the OP accepting this answer, taken from a comment by RiggsFolly was to also add:

```
date_default_timezone_set('UTC');
```

I would call this a joint venture and I can't take full credit for this.

Comment: Begs the question, what is yours and OP's `date.timezone ="???"` set to in your `php.ini` file.

Comment: @RiggsFolly I made an edit to the answer and that I don't know, since they're probably not my neighbour ;-)

Comment: I think this answers the question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19755820/php-date-and-daylight-savings-time-confusion

Comment: @RiggsFolly Good show on the "UTC" thing; I edited the answer giving you credit for it also; thanks for that ;-)

Comment: Ta, Cred not necessary. Call it "Team Work on an International basis", or "Hands across the water"

Comment: @RiggsFolly You're too modest. You deserved the mention since you also helped to solve it completely.